# Clear entry from Access Form UI but not DB, after saving record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

[image]

I will enter roll, grade and data entered by and click <kbd>Save Record</kbd> to save record in DB. I want the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button to only clear the entry in UI of Form and not in DB, so I can enter a new record instead of closing the form and opening it again to make new entry.

The `UndoRecord` macro works on the Form UI, only if the record hasn't been saved in DB. Also I dont want to delete the record, I just want to clear the entry from the Form UI after saving it.

Comment: Is your form bound or un-bound?

Comment: If form is BOUND just go to new record row. If form is UNBOUND then set textboxes to Null. Edit question to post attempted code. Might want to use a combobox for the 'data entered by' input.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic recipe for a *bound* form:

1. Set the form's DataEntry property to true (for instance in the form's Property Sheet).
2. Change the form's RecordSource query to contain an always-false statement in the WHERE clause, for example something like

---

```
SELECT Data.* FROM Data WHERE (True = False);
```

3. In the [Save Record] button click event handler, include code similar to the following:

---

```
Private Sub SaveRecord_Click()
  On Error Resume Next
  Me.Dirty = False 'Attempt to save the record
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Me.Requery 'Force the form to reload the query and reset the data entry form
  Else
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
  End If
End Sub
```

*Note*: The false criteria and setting `DataEntry = True` are actually redundant, since one or the other should be sufficient to keeping existing records from being shown in the form.  However, certain key combinations could allow navigation of the form whilst showing recently added records.  Having both of the settings ensures that only new records can be added without showing any saved records.

---

If you only want to clear the form with the clear button, leaving newly-added records available to review, then instead setup the following code:

```
Private Sub SaveRecord_Click()
  On Error Resume Next
  Me.Dirty = False 'Attempt to save the record
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    'Only enter a new record, leaving other newly-added record accessible
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
  Else
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub ClearForm_Click()
  On Error Resume Next
  Me.Dirty = False 'Attempt to save the record
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Me.Requery
  Else
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As you can see, I ignored any `UndoRecord` macro.  I'm not sure what that has to do with the desired solution, since if I understood the rest of the question, that would never have been useful since it does just want its name implies... it will undo the entry of a new record and prevent it from being saved.